# I am not getting City field in filtered in Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I used the below code to extract City and I_P_C from my data.

```
most_polluted_citites_by_industry = filtered_dataframe[['City_y','I_P_C']].groupby(["City_y"]).median().sort_values(by = 'I_P_C', ascending = True).tail(10)
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMwg5.png)

==================================================

Below are columns of my data frame.

[Image of old data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNlDv.png)

Comment: when you do groupby, that will become your index. so your cities are your index values

Comment: also, don't post pictures of the code and dataframe. Actually post the data or a sample of it so that we can reproduce your code. Also, but your code into code block.

Comment: @chitown88 Is it possible that I can get both Cities and their value by using groupby?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You have the cities and their values with the groupby here.

Comment: If you just add `.reset_index(drop=False)` to the end, you will move the cities to a column from the index.

Answer (score 0):

You have the cities there in the index. Just print the dataframe. Also, it's "cities" not "citities".

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Chicago', 34],
        ['New York', 23],
        ['Chicago', 56],
        ['Chicago', 4],
        ['New York', 67],
        ['Chicago', 2],
        ['Los Angeles', 17],
        ['Chicago', 15],
        ['Los Angeles', 99]]

columns = ['City_y','I_P_C']

filtered_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

most_polluted_cities_by_industry = filtered_dataframe[['City_y','I_P_C']].groupby(["City_y"]).median().sort_values(by = 'I_P_C', ascending = True).tail(10)
```

**Output:**

```
print(most_polluted_cities_by_industry)
             I_P_C
City_y            
Chicago       15.0
New York      45.0
Los Angeles   58.0
```